# Publish web job 3.x.x along with ASP.net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I trying to publish my web jobs along with my ASP.net core application whenever I publish it. With the ASP.net classic you could add web job as existing project

[image]

with ASP.net core there is no such option, so I added this to my `ProjectName.Api.csproj`

```
<Target Name="PostpublishScript" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="dotnet publish ..\ProjectName.WebJob\ -o $(PublishDir)App_Data\Jobs\triggered\ProjectName.WebJob" />
</Target>
```

based on the following [article](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/10/12/azure-webjobs-in-net-core-part-3/). When I publish my api, I see this in my output

```
dotnet publish ..\ProjectName.WebJob\ -o C:\sandbox\ProjectName\ProjectName.Api\obj\MockupApi\netcoreapp2.2\PubTmp\Out\App_Data\Jobs\triggered\ProjectName.WebJob
```

The asp.net project is successfully being published but the web job doesn't exist. In that article I see that the author has a folder called App_Data inside the bin folder, I don't have it in my `bin` but I have it my `obj` folder.

I also want to mention that I didn't have `App_Data` folder at all, I just created it for this purpose.